# Github latest release in npm package.json

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, package-managers

Ideally we always want the latest release version of a dependency we have specified in package.json, so that we don't have to manually bump up dependency version each time we make a release of it on Github.

Example of release dependecy in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
     "our-global-angular": "https://github.com/repo/global-angular.git#v2.0.1"
}
```

Is there a way to say `.git#latest` or `repo/releases/latest` to always get the newest release version with our package manager? And works on our private Github repos?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the branch name `user/project#branch`

```
"dependencies": {
     "our-global-angular": "https://github.com/repo/global-angular.git#master"
}
```

[doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies)

Comment: Sure, we could use master or a dedicated `current` branch to point to. But it would be nice to use the latest release version so that we don't get unwanted commits from master